# <io> de la <io>, but disambiguating between type and amount

Tags: word-meaning

As you know, "da" cannot be used when expressing amounts of specific things, and is replaced by "de la".

> Oni volas glason da vino.
>   Oni volas glason **de la** vino.

However, it seems to me that "glaso de la vino" can ambiguously mean either a wine glass for containing a specific wine (like "glaso de vino", but for **the** [specific] wine, whatever it is), or a glassful of a specific wine (like "glaso da vino", but for **the** [specific] wine).

I would expect that the usual expected meaning would be the latter, as one usually means to express an amount if one is saying such a thing, but what if I like to be really specific? How would one distinguish between "de la" meaning a type versus "de la" meaning an amount?

I guess "da tiu vino" and "de tiu vino" could be valid disambiguators, but what about the "la" case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope, that I understood your question correctly.

**1. glason da vino**

One can think, that the preposition *da* shows the [partitive case](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitivo), i.e.
*Mi volas glason da vino* : I want (some) wine a quantity, that measures up to a glass, a glass-full of wine.

**2. glason da ĉi tiu vino**

In the phrase *glason da ĉi tiu vino* the preposition *da* still shows the partitive like above, but this time the type of wine is limited to a specific one. In many current learning books this form is marked as erroneous, but there is an example in *Ekzecaro de la Fundamento* for this kind of use. See [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/da/nekutimaj_uzoj.html#i-tn7).

**3. glason de vino**

One of the most overloaded words, if not the most one, in Esperanto is the preposition *de* for which [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#de) gives 13 different meanings. One of those is to define the first part, i.e. *glason de vino* is a glass for wine, a wine glass.

**4. glason de la vino**

Actually I'm not sure what this phrase means other than misinterpreted case 2 above.